# Returning an event from a jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I return an event to the calling function to do something once the function has completed running.

jQuery Function

```
$.fn.myFunction(){
    this.each(function(){
        var it = $(this)
        setTimeout(function(){
            /* Return an event */
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

Call jQuery Function

```
$('div.specific').myFunction({
    'finish': function(element){
        /* Do something with element.
    }
});
```

Comment: i think you are  looking for callback.

Comment: Just use callback or a promise.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the "return an event" but I'm guessing you want to call `finish` function whenever something is finished.

I am not sure this is the best way, but it's something you can start with.

```js
$.fn.myFunction = function (object) {

 const _self = $(this);
 const init = () => {    
    if (object.hasOwnProperty('myCallback') && typeof object.myCallback === 'function') {
     _self.on('myEvent', object.myCallback)
    }
    
    _self.on('click', triggerCustomEvent)
  };
  
  const triggerCustomEvent = () => _self.trigger('myEvent')
  
  init();
}


$('#c').myFunction({
 myCallback: () => alert(123),
})
$('#d').myFunction({
 myCallback: () => alert(1234),
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <button id="c">Color</button>
  <button id="d">Dollar</button>
</div>
```